# Changing the location of the default public folder of nginx

Tags: nginx, centos

Let's say followed by [this question] I just asked, I am convinced that all my public web pages should be located at dir: `var/www` instead of what nginx creates by default, i.e `/usr/share/nginx/html`

So, the first thing I did was, edit the nginx config file to point to my `/www` folder.

```
location / {
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /var/www;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root   /var/www;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

But, the above approach does not work, it gives error even when restarting nginx. Saying that there is a configuration error.

So, is there a possible way to move put my projects in another directory?

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Would you mind to post the error? execute: "nginx -t" and paste the result here